# Python not comparing dates correctly?

Tags: python, html, date, flask, get

I'm trying to compare a few dates:

```
date1 = request.args['date1']
date2 = request.args['date2']
datesList = readFile('list.csv')
time.strptime(date1, "%d/%m/%Y")
time.strptime(date2, "%d/%m/%Y")
between = 0
for line in datesList:
    time.strptime(line[0], "%d/%m/%Y")
    time.strptime(line[1], "%d/%m/%Y")
    if line[0] <= date1 <= line[1]:
        between = 1
    if line[0] <= date2 <= line[1]:
        between = 2
    if date1 <= line[1] <= date2:
        between = 5
return render_template('index.html', vari = between)
```

I'm requesting the two input dates using a GET method and then converting them to date format using `strptime`. The datesList.csv looks like this:

```
17/11/2015,25/11/2015
1/11/2015,23/11/2015
17/12/2015,6/01/2016
28/10/2015,5/11/2015
```

If I enter dates like 04/05/2016 and 06/05/2016 it still returns `between = 5`. Is there something wrong with my code or am I using wrong functions?

Comment: You forgot to re-assign back the result of `strptime` to `date1` and `date2`. Same for the one inside the loop.

Comment: Yup, I did! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reaffect your values.

```
date1 = time.strptime(date1, "%d/%m/%Y")
date2 = time.strptime(date2, "%d/%m/%Y")

between = 0

for line in bookings:
    date1 = time.strptime(line[0], "%d/%m/%Y")
    date2 = time.strptime(line[1], "%d/%m/%Y")
    if line[0] <= date1 <= line[1]:
        between = 1
    if line[0] <= date2 <= line[1]:
        between = 2
    if date1 <= line[1] <= date2:
        between = 5
return render_template('index.html', vari = between)
```

Convert them to timestamps and then you can compare them as a number if it still does not work.

```
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, format).timetuple())
```

And your loop goes through "bookings" and I don't see it in your code. Is it a mistake?

Comment: Sorry, yes it was a mistake in this example. Bookings is supposed to be `datesList`.